# Windows 2008 R2 DHCP for two scope on two interfaces

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, subnet, dhcp-server, scope

I'm setting up a brand new DHCP Server over Windows 2008 R2 Standard edition server, and I'm planning to serv two differents lan with this one.

Here is my configuration:

1 AD/DNS/DHCP Server with following ETH setup:

ETH0 = PROD_SERVERS_LAN = VLAN100 = 10.30.0.0/24 Subnet.
ETH1 = PROD_CLIENTS_LAN = VLAN200 = 10.30.1.0/24 Subnet.

On the server I've set the following things:

AD = 1 Site with both subnets
DHCP = 2 scope

Now I wondering how can I be sure that my differents workstations/servers will ask and be answered by the correct scope?

I thought used the DHCP with NAP filtering but it seems to be buggy and heavy to manage.
Do you already have perform this kind of things with Windows infrastructure?

I'm able to do this with Linux Server, but I want to learn to do this things with Windows now.

Comment: Have you actually tested this yet? It seems to me that it should work "right out of the box".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All DHCP servers (and DHCP Proxies) will only issue IPs that lie within the subnet of the interface on which they issue the IP. So if you have two NICs with two different subnets, only IPs that match the subnet for the NIC will be issued on that NIC.

(Some DHCP server software is configurable enough to override this functionality; but is not the default)

Answer (score 0):

So, As guessed it joeqwerty my plateform is well working out of the box, I've just test it with two VM Clients who were on different VLan, and DHCP correctly handled the right scope.

Many thanks to joeqwerty and all those who have answered.

Answer (score -2):

Bad news. Windows Server 2008 R2 allow you to bind the DHCP to a specfied NIC but this binding is for the DHCP Service not for a specfied scope.

You will need to set up another server or VM to the other network segment or off course you can make a reservation based on the MAC for each PC but it dont think that it will very usefull.
Regards.

Comment: I have to say that I think you're wrong here. The DHPC service can bind to multiple adapters (multi-homed). That being said, if the DHCP server has scopes that encompasses the networks that it's NIC's are configured on then it should service DHCP clients from those scopes for those connected networks. This shouldn't be any different to having a single-homed DHCP server servicing DHCP clients on foreign subnets via a DHCP relay agent. The only difference is that the DHCPDiscover packets from each subnet will hit the DHCP server NIC directly instead of being forwarded by a relay.

Comment: Oh thank you for your clarifaction. Although we cannot bind a scope to an specific network card this should works. I was wrong. I just test it. Thank you @joeqwerty!!

Comment: Glad to pipe in my 2 cents (again). :)

Comment: My guess was that DHCP Server will be able to serv the correct lan with the correct scope because of the request incoming from ETH0 is incoming over a A network which (in any logical terms)should be serv by th A matching scope as explained it joeqwerty.

OK many thanks to everyone, I'll gonna do some tests with my Virtual machines.

Thanks again, efficient help on ServerFault, as usual ;).